# web scraping question: trying to store a specific value of my scrape into a var

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const request = require("request");
request("https://champion.gg/champion/Nautilus/Support?league=", (error, response, html) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
    {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var row = $('.footer-attr');
        var divvoorscript = row.prev().prev().html();
        //var physicaldmg = divvoorscript.find('physicalDmg');
        console.log(divvoorscript);
    }
});
```

This is what I'm currently using and it returns all this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhr1C.png

I'd like to save the value of "physicalDmg" "magicDmg" and "trueDmg" into 3 variables but have no idea how to go about this.

If someone could help me with this that'd be great!

Comment: The data in the image is really hard to read as it's not formatter. But probably you should first take a look at Riot API as they provide this data :)

Comment: You're scraping a `script` element, so you have to parse out just the json parts, or simply run it through eval(), which is not ideal https://runkit.com/lcherone/5db2fc5e76214b001a5417b6

Comment: Riot API doesn't collect that data and the champion.gg api seems to be defunct. Web scraping is my only option. I rain it through eval with the script you so kindly provided, but now I'm curious as to how I store the data in a variable.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks a lot